# How to unit test OnPropertyChanged event handler in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I'm running into the following issue with unit testing view models.

In my project, there are multiple view models (let's say A,B,C and D).
View Model A is the main view model where it is handling PropertyChanges coming from View models B,C, and D and then update the main view.

Most of the methods/properties in View Model A are unit testable except the event handler methods handling the propertychanged events from B,C and D.

For example:

```
public A()
{
  b.PropertyChanged += b_PropertyChanged;
  c.PropertyChanged += c_PropertyChanged;         
}


protected void b_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //process something based on the e.PropertyName 
  //might call some private or protected methods here to help with the processing
  switch(e.Property)
  {
     case "SearchResults":
        SearchResults = b.SearchResults;
        break;
  }   
}
```

How can i go about testing b_PropertyChanged without making it public?

Comment: Change a property in `b` or `c`? What's the problem?

Comment: What is it you want to test exactly? Some state in viewmodel A if a specific property is changed in viewmodel B etc.? Give an example of what your Asserts would be in your unit test if the b_PropertyChanged method was public.

Comment: Yes - A will handled any property changes in B or C

Comment: Ok - updated the code to include some more code for b_PropertyChanged. In my unit test, I would assert something like SearchResults is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a wrapper class to do this (see below) simply Use the testable class in its place and it will execute the code.

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestableProgram2 tp = new TestableProgram2();
        tp.b_PropertyChanged(new Program(), "bang");
    }
}

public class Program2
{
    protected void b_PropertyChanged(object sender, string e)
    {
        Debug.Write(e);
    }
}

public class TestableProgram2 : Program2
{
    public new void b_PropertyChanged(object sender, string e)
    {
         e = "altered";       // here to demonstrate this code is entered.
        base.b_PropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, creating a subclass of the class for testing purposes?

Comment: yes I've had to do this lots of times before, always irks me but it works. I just made a slight edit to make the sample actually work :) You can tell it works because the debug will output the altered string, you can remove that as its simply there to demonstrate its going through the public method to the base.

Comment: protected void b_PropertyChanged should be virtual right?

Comment: no because we are not using override we are hiding the method from the outside yet calling it inside. (ensure you are using my modified code. If you are calling a method from inside itself it will need to be virtual, but as written its cool (if you debug and set a breakpoint on `e="altered"` it should hit it then call the base method. If we were using override and attempted to change the visibility you'd get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

In these situations, it is customary to move the functionality out of the event handler and into its own method that can be called independently. You could try something like this:

```
protected void b_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    YourNewMethod(e.Property);
}

public void YourNewMethod(string propertyName)
{
    switch(propertyName)
    {
       case "SearchResults":
          SearchResults = b.SearchResults;
          break;
    }   
}
```

When testing, you can now call `YourNewMethod` to test that functionality.

Comment: Ok - should the NewMethod be set to public so that it can be unit tested?

Comment: you can move it out but if its protected you still can't call it, it'd have to be public which is not great. Wrapping is cleaner and doesn't involve altering object structure. Thats not to say that moving out the code in the event handler isn't a good idea :)

Comment: Yeah sorry... that's copy and pasting for you. ;) Updated now.